# Node proxy server modify response after query in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am troubling with nodejs proxy server modified(write) response.

I want to achieve auto login for one site via node proxy server and for that i have to query in database then i can modified response but it seems req ended before `req.write` and getting `Error: write after end`

Below is my implementation so far.

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var options = {
   target: 'http://example.com/', // target host
   changeOrigin: true,
   onProxyReq: function onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
    var _write = res.write;
    var body = "";

    proxyReq.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString('utf-8');
        body += data;
    });

    res.write = function (data) {
        try{
            //I have database query here instead of setTimeout
            setTimeout(function(){

                /* Modified response here and write */
                _write.call(res, data); //can't write because req already end

            },3000);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err',err);
        }
    }
  }
}

// create the proxy (without context)
var exampleProxy = proxy(options);
// mount `exampleProxy` in web server
var app = express();
app.use('/', exampleProxy);
app.listen(8080);
```

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a proxy at all, the point of a proxy is you let another server handle the request, looks to me like your still handling the request in the same server (unless I'm missing something).... why not just use normal express middleware?

Comment: @james Ok, I have one site that's too old and we can't make change into it. So requirement is create proxy server using expressjs and also want auto login because login session is not persistent.

Comment: But for auto login i have to inject one script into response and have username and password in it, but problem is i have to query in database for username and password then update response while this request is already ended.